# Require 'git' produce error

Tags: ruby, git

if i try to use `require 'git'` i get the following error

```
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/git-1.2.9.1/lib/git/lib.rb:917:in `command': git  version   2>&1:Der Befehl "git" ist entweder falsch geschrieben oder (Git::GitExecuteError)
konnte nicht gefunden werden.
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/git-1.2.9.1/lib/git/lib.rb:824:in `current_command_version'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/git-1.2.9.1/lib/git/lib.rb:834:in `meets_required_version?'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/git-1.2.9.1/lib/git.rb:25:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
        from HappyProject.rb:5:in `<main>'
```

for me it almost looks like there is a problem with the git gem so i used

```
gem uninstall git
gem install git
```

still no change to the error

iam only starting with ruby and rly cant find any solotuion for this ...

first few lines of my script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'win32console'
require 'colorize'
require 'fileutils'
require 'git'

def GREEN_TEXT() return "\033[32m" end
def BROWN_TEXT() return "\033[33m" end
def GRAY_TEXT()  return "\033[37m" end
```

ruby version 1.9.3p551

git gem version 1.2.9.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In 99% of cases, if a computer tells you that it couldn't find something, it is because the thing to find isn't there. In 99% of the rest of cases, you haven't told it to look in the right place.

So, the first two things to check are:

1. Do you have Git installed? If not, install it.
2. Is it in your `%PATH%`? If not, add it.

Comment: thanks ... git was installed and it was also in the path (... at some point) ... since i normaly use the git bash for git i didnt even noticed that it wasnt in the path anymore so that solved it ....
i wasn't even aware that ruby needs git isntalled.
so big thanks ;)

Comment: Ruby doesn't need Git installed, but the Git gem obviously does, since it uses Git. That's kind of its purpose.